# Outlook shows image as attachment which is referenced in the HTML body of the mail

Tags: outlook, mime-types, mime, email-processing

I just received a mail with an attachment that was an image, it has the file ending .emz. The mail is a HTML mail and the body references this image. Do you have to treat this image as a real attachment or is it inline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a compressed Windows Metafile picture, usually created when an RTF email with embedded OLE attachments is converted to HTML.